# Как подключить boost.asio к qt creator на ubuntu?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, boost, boost.asio

Как подключить boost.asio к qt creator на ubuntu? Возникли проблемы с подключением asio потому что библиотека является заголовочной, ее бинарники отсутствуют в папке с бустом. Следовательно через функцию "подключить библиотеку", предлагаемую qt creator ее подключить нельзя, т.к. функция
просит бинарный файл. Вопрос состоит в том, что нужно написать в .pro файле, чтоб я спокойно мог пользоваться asio?

Comment: ну если библиотека установлена из пакетов, то ничего не нужно

Comment: @user7860670, а если в ручную?

Comment: во-первых, если "библиотека" загаловочная, то это и не библиотека в понимании компилятора. Единственное что нужно: указать пути к хидерам через опцию `-I` компилятора. И не используйте `IDE` зависимые вещи - вы же ставите крест ни то что на переносимости между платформами, а даже на использовании отличной `IDE` от вашей (даже оличной версии `IDE`!). Используйте `cmake` ну или на худой канец `qmake`

Comment: @DenverToha boost.asio можно поставить несколькими способами - через пакетный менеджер как часть буста (самый правильный способ), можно собрать буст ручками (плохой способ для начинающих). Скачать отдельно буст.асио. Какой способ выбирали Вы?